# Create object from array inside object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object like this with an array inside it:

```
    Abc Object
(
   [attributes:protected] => Array
       (
           [id] => xx
           [entity] => payment
           [amount] => 1475047
           [order_id] =>
           [invoice_id] =>
           [created_at] => 1558350389
       )
)
```

How do I get `id`, `entity`, `amount`, `invoice_id`, `order_id` as an object from it?

**Edit**
The call to external API:

```
    $api = new Api($dbres[0]['api_key'], $dbres[0]['secret_key']);
   $payment = $api->payment->fetch($validationObj['paymentReference']);
   $respObj = $payment->capture(array('amount' => $validationObj['amount'])) ;

   print_r($respObj);exit;
```

Comment: echo `$yourVariableName->amount` like this?

Comment: If the `attributes` is protected you need GET method to access it outside the object

Comment: You can't because it is a proctected variable. That means you can only access that variable from the class itself or from a class derived from that class.

Comment: @dWinder i am getting it as response from an external API. how to access protected variables inside object array

Comment: But we don't know how is that API building that result...

Comment: Does the API have any documentation ? Because with the provided information, we can't help you.

Comment: @Amarnasan https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/#capture-a-payment

Comment: Looks like the responses is in json, how does your Abc Object is build from the json ?

Comment: @Frankich  what i've posted is how i am getting the response(part of the response)

Comment: No the provided post is a dump of an object, how do you build this object ? where is the `json_decode($response)` and the `new Abc($response);` or whatever of your code ? My question is where come from the Abc Object ,can you post the code of the class ?

Comment: So the class API has an object which have `payement` as name and use the `fetch` method on it which return an object which has a `capture` method and return an other object. So if you want to have access to these value you have to follow the entire process in these class, and either change the method which provide those variable as protected to public, of find out if there is a magic method `__get()` implemented to have access to your attributes like `$respobj->id`, we can't help you more since we don't have the code of the Api class

Comment: ok there is a `public function __get($key)   {  return $this->attributes[$key];  }` so you just have to call `$respObj->WhateverYourAttribute` or change in ` razorpay-php/src/Resource.php` the protected `$attribute` to public, but it's not a good thing to do IMO

Comment: @Frankich that gives me the result of that attribute.. how do I get it as an object

Comment: `$o = new StdClass(); foreach($respObj->getIterator() as $key => $value) { $o->$key = $value;}`somthing like this

Comment: @Frankich thank you very much.. please write as answer and i will accept..tomorrow.

Comment: that's is fine, I do not need reputation. Good luck